# names for "sub" discrete topology

Tags: general-topology, terminology

Given a finite discrete set $X$. Its powerset $P(X)$ is often referred to as discrete topology.

I'm wondering what are the names for the topology of $X$: $S(X)$ ? Which is only a proper subset of $P(X)$.

$S(X) \subset P(X)$.

I'm not interested in a general subset of (), but the ones are the topology of $X$.

And $S(X) \neq \emptyset$, so it's not the other popular topology trivial topology.

Comment: Well, in general $S(X)$ may not even be a topology from what I read

Comment: right, but i'm not interested in a general subset of $P(X)$, but the ones are topology and do they have names in general

Comment: I do not think there is a name in the literature honestly

Comment: A topology that is not discrete could be called just “non-discrete”.

Comment: it's apparently coarser than discrete, I'd attempt to use "coarser-discrete topology". not sure if "non-discrete" is as informative.

Comment: @pengyu But every topology is (non-strictly) coarser than discrete, so “non-discrete” carries all the information.

Comment: right, and among the $S(X)$, there are ones that is finer and coarser, this is where i want to find the right terminology to properly present them

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_topologies .

Answer (score 0):

In fact, $\mathcal{T}=P(X)$ is always knwon as the discrete topology (for both finite and infinite sets). It's a topology you can put on any set.

Any *proper subset* of $P(X)$ that is a topology is just called a *non-discrete* topology, if it's given a name at all.

The trivial, or indiscrete, topology s just $\{\emptyset, X\}$, the minimal topology on any set $X$.